# Where can i ask to increase space quota for launchpad ppa?

Tags: ppa, repository, packaging, launchpad

I did put an question in launchpad answers but i think there is only one guy active on the help desk of launchpad. Where can i ask to increase my ppa space quota? I'm newbie & trying to maintain ppa for research & development tools like ADT, android studio, gem5, JPPF, Scilab etc. I'm not understanding the problem is it my english, nationality or my color ?
BTW  the link for question on lauchpad is [Lauchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/245815) for my ppa

> ppa:linuxgndu/gajj-sci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the question in the right place, but since you seem to be uploading binaries into your PPA rather than source code, the chances that you will get a size increase is small. PPAs are meant to have open-source software, where the sources are uploaded, and binaries are built on Launchpad's servers. If you want to use this software on your own computer, you don't need a PPA for this.

I know for a fact that Android Studio is [open-source](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/platform/tools/adt/idea), and gem5 is also [open-source](http://gem5.org/Download) (although it has some closed-source parts), so one of your reasons is invalid.

Another reason source packages are built for each Ubuntu release is because there are different libraries and library version in each release, and so a binary that works on one release may or may not work on another release. Source packages are also built for each architecture because while an i386 application can technically run on amd64, it requires the use of i386 libraries, whereas an amd64 application only requires amd64 libraries (amd64 applications cannot be run on i386). In addition, different architectures have different "defaults" (an `int` may be 2 bytes instead of 4 bytes), and each application has to be built on each architecture to account for that.

Comment: @salarcot895 Sir but i'm using different binaries for each architecture. For gem5 i'm using it's source code(i'm putting SC in the package but not builing from it), but in near future i will be provide an interface so that user can build gem5 according to his/her needs (like alpha,arm,opt or using any other option), but for the time i'm putting source code of gem5 in the package. And for the different versions of ubuntu they are giving same binaries under the category Linux, if in near future i will encounter problem for that i will try to solve it. Gratitude for your answer.